# Is it possible to detect call events in OSX?

Tags: iphone, macos

There is a feature to receive phone calls on OSX ([see official Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18756?locale=en_US)). Is it possible to have some kind of daemon listen for this event and react on it? I assume that your iPhone and your Mac are connected to each other.

Comment: Have you found out anything related to this?